# The correct way to include connection using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Below is my code under db.php

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');

/* check connection */
if (!$con) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>
```

Under index.php I include db.php and functions.php as:

```
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");
```

functions.php is also using the db.php connection. I don't have problem before when using mysql. But after I change mysql to mysqli I got an error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in" in my functions.php.

This is the function under functions.php that has an error:

```
function get_type($r_id){
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "select type from rooms where id=$r_id") or die("select type from rooms where id=$r_id"."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['type'];
}
```

My solution is to add db.php in every function under functions.php that calls mysqli like:

```
function get_type($r_id){
    include("includes/db.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "select type from rooms where id=$r_id") or die("select type from rooms where id=$r_id"."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['type'];
}
```

I am wondering if this is the correct solution.

Comment: The `or die`-style error handling is **horrible**. Use a single wrapper function that calls `mysqli_query` and then checks for an error and in that case logs/displays the error and exists!

Comment: [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) works pretty well; is it not available? It's a pretty decent wrapper for MySQL connectivity...

Comment: Also note that `mysql_` and `mysqli_` are NOT the same and you can't just "add an `i`" and expect it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $con is not available to your functions

You can add another argument to each function

```
function get_type($con, $r_id)...
```

and then pass $con into it

```
include('includes/db.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
$blah = get_type($con, 5);
```

OR

You can make $con accessible to each function by adding this `global $con;` for example

```
function get_type($r_id){
    global $con;
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "select type from rooms where id=$r_id") or die("select type from rooms where id=$r_id"."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['type'];
}
```

The choice my friend.. is yours

(there may be other ways to skin this cat)

Comment: is global $con; safe within function level? because I've read that using global is not advisable, may be if it is within module level. please correct my understanding. thanks

Comment: @jaypabs - See, the problem with `global $var` is they are so easy to overwrite accidentally. I would caution against this approach, although if you're really careful and don't have a large codebase sprawling over several files (ie, limited complexity and opportunity to screw up) it could work. Try looking for singleton approaches to setting/getting one `$con`.

Comment: I was just offering a couple of solutions to the problem @jaypabs, personally I would go for adding another argument to my functions and passing the already set $con in to them.

Answer (score 0):

set `$con` global in function:

```
function get_type($r_id){
    global $con;
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "select type from rooms where id=$r_id") or die("select type from rooms where id=$r_id"."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['type'];
}
```